# Assigning a list to a value of existing list from another class

Tags: java

I want to create an instance of a list and assigned to the value of same type of list from another class.

The original variable to be copied is here

```
class A {
     List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>();
     //Some calculation and the value of copy is now holding some information
}
```

The class I want to create a new instance and assigned to the previous value

```
class B extends A {
     List<String> paste = new ArrayList<>(copy);
}
```

It didn't throw any errors, but the list is still empty. Does anyone hava any idea what's going on here and how to compute such things?

Comment: Where are you doing the calculations? In an instance initialization block? A method? Constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>First a hint: You should use generics properly. Use `new ArrayList<String>`.</del>

`copy` is a field of the class A. `paste` is a field of class B (extending A). Therefore when a new object (lets call it o) of Class B is created the following happens:

- o.copy = ...
- o constructor for class A is executed
- o.paste = ...
- o constructor for class B is executed

If you need detailed information about Java's object initialization process, [this is an excellent article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html) about that.

If the `Some calculation` part is not done within A's constructor it will not be reflected in B's initial values.

Let me try to formulate a solution:

```
class A {
     List<String> copy;
     //constructor
     public A() {
       copy = new ArrayList<>();
       //Some calculation and the value of copy is now holding some information
     }
}

class B extends A {
     List<String> paste;
     //constructor
     public B() {
       super(); //calls the A constructor and fills copy
       paste = new ArrayList<>(copy);
     }
}
```

Comment: By the way I have to correct myself. Your usage of `ArrayList<>` is the new Java 7 way of removing redundant class specifications. I wasn't aware of that until just now.

Answer (score 1):

```
class B extends A {
   List<String> paste = copy;
}
```

Comment: This would make `paste` point to the same `List`. It does not create a copy!

Answer (score 0):

... `= new ArrayList<>(argument)`; you can pass number or iteratable object to the argument

You need to assign with,

```
class B extends A {
     List<String> paste = copy;
}
```

This code will assign reference of `copy` object of `class A` to local object of `class B`.

To create clone,

```
List<String> paste = (ArrayList<String>)copy.clone();
```

Comment: This would make paste point to the same List. It does not create a copy!

Comment: Yes, you are right man, this will create a new object referring same object.

Comment: Ya. I tried that, and like you said, the list is still empty.

Comment: It'll assign your empty copy list's reference to paste object of class `B`

Answer (score 0):

The `paste` list is created implicitly in the default constructor of class `B`. This constructor contains at first possibility an implicit call to the default constructor of `A`, which creates the `copy` list.

Depending on when your calculations take place the 'copy' list may be empty on construction time of class `B`.

To get this right the calculations must be called inside the constructor of `A`.